# HTMLInputElement has no method 'val'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looping through cells in a table row. each cell has a text box in it, and I want to take the value of the text box and push it onto an array.

```
function dothing() {
        var tds = $('#'+selected+' td');
        var submitvals = new Array();
        tds.each(function(i) {
            var val = $(this).children('input')[0].val();
            submitvals.push(val);
        });
    }
```

Theres more to the function, but this is all that is relevant. For some reason, when I run this code, I get "HTMLInputElement has no method 'val'." I thought that input elements were supposed to have a `val()` method in jQuery that got the value so this makes no sense. Am I missing something, or doing it wrong?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`val()` is a jQuery method. `.value` is the DOM Element's property. Use `[0].value` or `.eq(0).val()`....

Answer (score 15):

`.val()` is a jQuery function, not a javascript function. Therefore, change:

```
var val = $(this).children('input')[0].val()
```

To:

```
var val = $(this).children('input:eq(0)').val()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function dothing() {
    var tds = $('#'+selected+' td');
    var submitvals = new Array();
    tds.each(function(i) {
        var val = $($(this).children('input')[0]).val();
        submitvals.push(val);
    });
}
```

Comment: yes, agree with you, but i wanted to show that val() method it's method of $(), non a DOM element.

Answer (score 2):

.val() is a jquery method. Using [0] returns the DOM element, not the jquery element

```
var val = $(this).children('input:first').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

What I don't understand, is why none of the suggested syntaxes on this or other questions similar to this seem to work for me. I had to do trial and error and eventually had to use:

MySelectElement.value = x;

It also didn't help that the Visual Studio Intellisense suggestions offer a whole other range of unworking method names, such as ValueOf().