# Jquery get value and display in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, html

i've got a select field with few options, each of them has assigned "value" attribute and they got names. Upon selecting one of the options, I want one  to be filled with the title, second one with the value. Title works fine, but I can't get it to catch the assigned "value="asd"" value.

```
   $(".itemclass").on("change", function () {
        $("span.iclass").text(this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent);
        $("span.impl").text(this.options[this.selectedIndex].val());
    });
```

What am I missing?

Comment: try `$(this.options[this.selectedIndex])` instead

Comment: Don't use `.val()` on a DOM element. That's a jQuery method. Use `.value` instead. Also, for `option` elements specifically, you can use `.text` instead of `.textContent`.

Comment: @cookiemonster changing val to value fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I did a little fiddling pardon the pun.

Here is what I came up with.

```
$(".itemclass").change(function()
{
    $("#Name").text(this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent);
    $("#Value").text(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
 });
```

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/nH2a3/

Here is where I found your solution Check out the answer for this question for the why.

[HTMLInputElement has no method 'val'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332698/htmlinputelement-has-no-method-val)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can access the selected option:

```
$(".itemclass").on("change", function () {
    var selectedOption = $(this).find("option:selected");
    $("span.iclass").text(selectedOption.text());
    $("span.impl").text(selectedOption.val());
});
```

Or alternatively if you prefer to use the DOM node:

```
$(".itemclass").on("change", function () {
    var selectedOption = $(this).find("option:selected").get(0);
    $("span.iclass").text(selectedOption.textContent);
    $("span.impl").text(selectedOption.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
$(".itemclass").on("change", function () {
    $("span.iclass").text(this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent);
    $("span.impl").text($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try with this code:

```
$(".itemclass").on("change", function () {
    $("span.iclass").text($(this).find("option:selected").text());
    $("span.impl").text($(this).find("option:selected").val());
});
```